# Assume that $g(x)$ is an even function, and also that $\int_0^5 g(x) dx=3$ and $\int_5^7 g(x) dx=4$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume that g(x) is an even function, and also that $\int_0^5 g(x) dx=3$ and $\int_5^7 g(x) dx=4$.

Find $\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx$ and $\int_{-5}^7 g(x) dx$

**My attempt**

$$\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx=\int_0^5 g(x) dx + \int_{5}^{-5} g(x) dx$$

$$=3-\int_{-5}^5 g(x) dx$$
$$=3-2\int_{0}^5 g(x)$$
$$=3-2(3)=-3$$

$$\int_{-5}^{7} g(x) dx=\int_{-5}^5 g(x) dx + \int_{5}^7 g(x) dx$$
$$=2\int_{0}^5 g(x) + \int_{5}^7 g(x) dx$$
$$=2(3)+4=10$$

Can anyone please verify my answers

Comment: Yes, your answers are correct.

Comment: Now, you changed the limits of integration and it is wrong again in the first line. $\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx=\int_0^5 g(x) dx \color{red}{-} \int_{5}^{-5} g(x) dx$ schould be  $\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx=\int_0^5 g(x) dx \color{green}{+} \int_{5}^{-5} g(x) dx$ The calculation afterwards is correct.

Comment: Now, I made correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction:

$$\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx=\int_0^5 g(x) dx + \int_{\color{red}5}^{\color{red}{-5}} g(x) dx$$

$$=3-\int_{-5}^5 g(x) dx$$
$$=3-2\int_{0}^5 g(x)$$
$$=3-2(3)=-3$$

Or faster way:

$$\int_0^{-5} g(x) dx=-\int_{-5}^0 g(x) \, dx=-\int_0^5 g(x)\, dx=-3$$

Comment: So, my answer was correct

Comment: yes, answer is correct.